# Changing a UILabel's text attribute according to where the segue was preformed

Tags: swift, xcode

My issue here is that I would like to change a UILabel's text according to which button triggered the segue. My identifier of my QuestionViewController (second view controller) is "goToQuestion", I have 2 buttons a truth and a dare button, they're both UI Buttons that can perform segues to the QuestionViewController, now the main question is how can I update the my UILabel to say Truth if the segue was performed through the truthPressed UIButton and to say dare if segue was performed through darePressed, I'm sure it requires and if and else statement that has to be in the QuestionViewController, or an " if segue.identifier = darePressed ... " I'm just confused and would like someone to enlighten me

```
@IBAction func truthPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToQuestion", sender: self)
    }

@IBAction func darePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToQuestion", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Override `prepareForSegue`, either keep a variable to know which button was pressed, and read it inside the prepareForSegue, or if you have two `IBOutlet`, pass it as `sender` instead of `self` and read the parameter, or in sender send some other variable you want and read it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `prepare(for segue:`

```
@IBAction func truthPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToQuestion", sender: "truth")
}

@IBAction func darePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToQuestion", sender: "dare")
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
    if let des = segue.destination as? QuestionViewController { 
        des.sentValue = sender as! String 
    } 
}
```

With

```
class QuestionViewController:UIViewController { 
    var sentValue = "" 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        print(sentValue)
    }
}
```